# modal's Identity Inspector Not Applicable

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xcode5

After I set a modal from one view to another. I click that line between them, but I can't change the Identity in Identity Inspector.
It shows Not Applicable!
I googled, finding no solution. Is there who can help me? Thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "change the Identity", but if you mean the identifier, you don't do that in the Identity Inspector, you do it in the Attributes Inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't show Identity Inspector available for any of my modal or push's what did you need that for? Are you trying to change the transition or something different?